# Error in the function icvCreateHidHaarClassifierCascade

Tags: opencv

This function is showing error . I am using opencv in c++
how can we use this function

Comment: For some weird reason my cristal ball is not working today. What's the error?

Comment: I want to know  what is the diff between icvCreateHidHaarClassifierCascade(cascade) and CvHaarClassifierCascade . As i am not able to use the formaer function in my code , it gives the error (function not declared in this scope) Please help

Answer (score 0):

CvHaarClassifierCascade is a structure in opencv to represent the entire detector cascade. HidHaarClassifierCascade is a structure within it which represents the hidden (optimized) representation of the cascade. The actual computations are carried through the hidden cascade. icvCreateHidHaarClassifierCascade( cascade ) is an internal function ( thats why the initial 'i' ) to create that hidden cascade. It is called from the function cvhaardetectobjects. The internal functions are not declared in header files, so you cannot call it, same is true for any functions starting with 'icv'.

Comment: Then how can we use HidHaarClassifierCascade is a structure

Comment: you'll have to be more specific. where do you want to use it?